# unsigned integer overflow error in gcc(TDM-GCC)?

Tags: c++, gcc, integer-overflow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cinttypes>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint16_t i = 0;
    cout << USHRT_MAX << '\n' << i - 1 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
65535
-1
```

I expected two equal outputs, but it wasn't. Isn't this a non-standard-compliant behaviour?

*System: Windows7

*Compile Option: g++ -o $(FileNameNoExt) $(FileName) -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. But I'm having trouble finding a good target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When C++ sees the expression

```
i - 1
```

it automatically promotes `i` and 1 to `int` types, so the result of the expression is an `int`, hence the output of -1.

To fix this, either cast the overall result of the expression back to `uint16_t`, or do something like

```
i--;
```

to modify `i` in-place, then print `i`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: cout << USHRT_MAX << '\n' << i - (uint16_t)1 << '\n'; why doesn't this work?

Comment: IIRC, all integer computations in C++ are done by promoting the operands to `int`s or `unsigned int`s, so the type of the expression you get by subtracting two `uint16_t`'s should be `int` or `unsigned int`. If you cast the overall expression, then you force the type back to `uint16_t`.

Comment: @xiver77: This answer is somewhat wrong with respect to the reason. The type of 1 is not the cause. The cause is *default promotions*. Neither C nor C++ actually support performing *any* arithmetic with types smaller than `int`.

Comment: @R.. Would it be safe to say that the issue is that C++ automatically promotes the arguments to integer types, hence the issue? I would like to edit this answer to be as correct as possible.

Comment: In C, the cases where the integer promotions are applied are: "as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the shift operators"

Comment: "usual arithmetic conversions" refers to the process of determining a common type for a binary arithmetic operator. Each operator specifies whether it performs those conversions or not (binary `+` does).

Comment: @R.. Answer updated - how does it look? And thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

`i` is promoted to an int **before** the evaluation of `i - 1`, so the expression `i - 1` is itself evaluated as a signed integer (`int`), try :

```
cout << USHRT_MAX << '\n' << (uint16_t)(i - 1) << '\n';
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2662363cf455d25)